# Is there any handler that can detect if a select field has any option selected without jQuery

Tags: javascript, dom-events

When an option is selected that wasn't previously, the `onChange` handler can detect this. How can a preselected option be detected (i.e., whether a select field has any option selected)? Is this possible without jQuery? Is there a handler, such as `onSelected` (not the same as `onSelect` for highlighted text) for this event?

Example:

```
<select onSelected="FunctionRunIfOptionSelected()">
<option> ... </option>
...
</select>
```

The preselected option will have been selected on page load. i.e., with the HTML dynamically rendered:

```
<option selected> ... </option>
```

Comment: Is the preselected value always the same? Or is it unknown?

Comment: @CrazyTrain It is unknown

Comment: Can you modify the rendering of the select? If so, you could use a `data-` attribute to give the `select` a reference to the original index, like `data-selected=4`. Then just compare in your handler `if (select_elem.getAttribute("data-selected") !== select_elem.selectedIndex) {...`

Comment: I'm still not clear on when you want this handler to run.

Comment: What exactly is an example of what you'd like to be able to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, the task is to tell if an option has the selected attribute hard-coded into the HTML? If so, this should work:

```
function test () {
    var opts = document.getElementById("myselect").options;
    var i, len = opts.length;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (opts[i].getAttribute("selected" ) != null ) { // opts[i] has the selected attribute
            change_other_select(i); // pass the option index to your other function
            break;
        }
    }
}

window.onload = test;
```

The trick is to distinguish between the selected property and the selected attribute, and also between a null value and an empty string.

Comment: Yes, but this is a function that must be called to check if an option is selected. How can whether or not an option is selected be automatically detected, like the onChange() handler automatically detects when an option is changed?

Comment: I'm confused. An option is always selected. I really don't know what you need that hasn't been answered somewhere. Maybe you could ask it another way? (Sorry.)  WAIT!! Do you mean you want to know if a _specific_ option is selected?

Comment: The option selected for the select field will determine what options will be loaded in the second selectbox. This works fine when I change the option of the first selectbox. But what if the page is loaded in which an option is hardcoded with the selected attribute? It will not automatically load the second selectbox's options.

Comment: I made some adjustments to my code. By **change_other_select** I mean the function that updates your second selectbox. I assume you have code for that, and I imagine that it needs to know the index of the selected element in the first selectbox, so that's how I'm calling it. I've also shown how to execute the function when the page loads. There are other ways; this is the simplest. -- Be aware that if the user changes the option and then reloads the page, this function won't work right. But let's see if we're in the right ballpark, first.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myselect = document.getElementByid('selectid');         
myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect if the select field does not have the default value selected like this:

```
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
for (i=0;i<selects.length;i++) {
    if (selects[i].selectedIndex != 0) {
        eval(selects[i].getAttribute("onSelected"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I can call a function when the select value is changed. But what event handler can call a function when the select already has a value on page load? For example, if the page is loaded with a particular option selected, how to call a function? OnChange="Function()" won't work then.

Comment: The select tag always has an option selected.  It's always the first one, unless otherwise specified.  Are you saying you want to detect if the option selected is not the default one?

Comment: Yes. Is there an event that can detect this and call a function? Like onChange

Comment: What I'm trying to have done is, say in your Jsfiddle, you have `<option value="chicken" selected>Two</option>`. How can you have it so it detects that an option is selected and so displays "chicken" once the page loads? Currently it waits until you change the value.

Answer (score 0):

To test for selected option on page load, you'll need to catch these in the `window.onload` handler

One the page is loaded you'll need to continue to use the `onChange` handler, but use `selectedIndex` property to test if this is populated with an index within your option list.

Alternatively give your options values in the HTML and check the values themselves. This will allow deterministic behavior when expanding the option list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the `.options[]` and `.selectedIndex` methods you can handle this cleanly and unobtrusively like so:

HTML

```
<select name="select" id="select">
    <option value="">...</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Two</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
window.onload = function(){
    var select = document.getElementById("select"), selected = select.value;
    select.onchange = function(){
        var val = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        if(val != selected) {
            alert("Another value " + val + " was selected, which is not the same as the default value of " + selected);
        } else {
            alert("Same value as the default of " + selected + " was selected");
        }
    };
};
```

From within the JS, you can check and manipulate the `val` variable as you like.

Comment: The onChange handler detects when the value is changed. What kind of handler can detect when a value other than the default is selected? Such as if one of the options was dynamically rendered <option selected>One</option> ?

Comment: The `onchange` works just fine for that, just grab the initial value and store it in a variable and use a conditional to check the values. I've updated my answer to do just that.